# JavaScript generated elements not functioning - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table as below;

```
<table id="mytable">
    <tr>
        <td>cola1</td>
        <td>cola2</td>
        <td>cola3</td>
        <td class="rem">cola4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>colb1</td>
        <td>colb2</td>
        <td>colb3</td>
        <td class="rem">colb4</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button id="but">Add Row</button>
```

A button `<button id="but">mybutton</button>` is placed at bottom of table, which on click, adds a new row to the table. The last column of rows have class `rem`, which has a function to remove the parent row on click.

Here is the javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#but').click(function() {
        row = $("<tr></tr>");
        col1 = $('<td>colex1</td>');
        col2 = $('<td>colex2</td>');
        col3 = $('<td>colex3</td>');
        col4 = $('<td class="rem">colex4</td>');
        row.append(col1,col2,col3,col4).prependTo("#mytable");
    });

    $('.rem').click(function() {
        var $button = $(this);
        var $row = $button.closest('tr');
        $row.fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

The function work well in above two rows. But remove button is not working in rows added by jQuery. How can I make the Javascript added rows work like others?

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/Nug2b/1/)** is the fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a delegated event handler, using [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on), if you want it to apply to newly created elements.  The way this works is by adding the handler to an element that already (and continues) to exist in the DOM, then in the handler, as the event bubbles up, it checks whether the event target matches the selector supplied to the `on()` function.  If so, then it runs the handler otherwise it doesn't.

```
$('#mytable').on('click','.rem',function() {
  var $button = $(this);
  var $row = $button.closest('tr');
  $row.fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Comment: Or just add it when the field is created on click of the button.

Comment: can you give me a fiddle please.. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think a lot of it comes down to how you handle the functionality. You could use `$.on()` or some other listener, but I don't think it's necessary if you know when you're adding the element and it's entirely under your control.

For instance:

**EDIT** - Fixed having the `click` handler on the row, put it on the `.rem` element instead.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $row = $("<tr>"),
        $col1 = $('<td>colex1</td>'),
        $col2 = $('<td>colex2</td>'),
        $col3 = $('<td>colex3</td>'),
        $col4 = $('<td class="rem">colex4</td>');

    var addrow = function() {
        $row.clone(true).prependTo("#mytable");
    };

    var removerow = function() {
        var $button = $(this),
            $row = $button.closest('tr');

        $row.fadeOut('slow');
    };

    $row.append($col1, $col2, $col3, $col4);
    // This could be $($col4).click(removerow);, too.
    $row.find('.rem').click(removerow);

    $('#but').click(addrow);
    $('.rem').click(removerow);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sM2R8/4/

Now this uses caching of the new `$row` with a [`$.clone(true)`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) to copy the click handlers that have been added. If you want to change the values, you'll need to clone and then update those values, but that's just a nuance to how you want to handle this. You could, also, just add the `removerow` handler to the cloned element before/after you append it to the table, too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#mytable').on('click', '.rem', function() {
  var $button =$(this);
  // ...
});
```

By doing that, you establish a handler on the table itself that listens for events bubbling up from contained elements. The second argument is a selector against which the actual target element is tested. If it matches (in this case, if it's a "remove" button), then your handler function is called.

Thus you can add as many rows as you like, and each new button's events will be intercepted by the same handler.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
.live(event, handler)
```

In this case event handler will be attached to the future elements also.
so use:

```
$('.rem').live('click', function() {
  var $button = $(this);
  var $row = $button.closest('tr');
  $row.fadeOut('slow');
});
```

However as of jQuery 1.7 live() is deprecated, use on()

Comment: Unless you're using a really old version of jQuery, don't use `.live()`. It's deprecated. Even if you have a moderately old version, you'd use `.delegate()` instead of `.live()`.

Comment: Well, first, [`$.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated, and if you review my answer (or really the `$.on()`, if you want to be picky), you'll notice that's not necessarily true.

Comment: @JaredFarrish is right. To say you *must* use it is flat out wrong.

Comment: +1 Thanks! Didn't know live() is deprecated. Actually I am hosting the latest version of jQuery and live is functioning perfectly.

Comment: @MarkBrittingham: By easy to understand, I assume you mean nearly always misunderstood, and therefore abused.

Comment: ***deprecated*** does not equal ***removed*** ([see the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation)). Something is deprecated when it is going to be removed, but hasn't yet. It's a warning period that it will eventually be removed, and should be avoided. It also should be noted that even if it's never removed, it should be avoided in practice, and in the case of `$.live()`, performance reasons dictate it should be avoided (which is why it was deprecated).

Comment: @lukas.pukenis: Yes it still works. Deprecated means it's going to stop working in the future.

Comment: @am not I am - lol.  Ok, gotcha. Looking at the .on link that you and others posted makes it pretty clear why .live is deprecated. Looks easy enough to update my old .live() references.

Answer (score 1):

Your click handler works on existing rows only because they do exist when you call it. For future elements not in the DOM though you need to use a delegation method that accounts for both current and future elements. To do this use on() delegated to the table ( or element further up that will always exist) and add the button class as selector

```
$('#mytable').on('click','.rem',function() {
   var $button = $(this);
  var $row = $button.closest('tr');
  $row.fadeOut('slow');
});
```